# Making html game. Having trouble with gif positioning for the character in js. (not using any js libraries)

Tags: javascript, html, css

This is a link with the folder called js game. i have uploaded the folder due to the images being locally downloaded. i posted a previous question without the images and figured id make it more convenient for anyone who wants to help.
https://www.mediafire.com/folder/augcbx9usunwm/js+game

There are going to be levels in my game and the way i have built up the html css js is every level is going to have its own external js file which will be called in. The character js file includes adding its character gif and the controls for the gif. When the new image is appended to the body it shows and has a few attributes. src, id, height, width. i also want to add in style. to be specific i want to add left and bottom to set the character bottom left of the screen. i am happy for the characters left and bottom positioning to be in css instead of js, but i would rather js.
the css file is going to have ALL the games css. i have attempted this in both js and css files and kept my attempt for yous to look at.

Here is the code from the html file "js game.html", code from the js file "girl_flying.js, code from the css file "game.css"

```js
//start of image create

var img = new Image(150, 150); // width, height
img.src = "sprites/characters/girl flying left.gif";
img.id = "girl_flying";
img.style.position = "absolute";
top = 100;
left = 100;
document.body.appendChild(img);

//end of image create

//start of flying girl controlls

var
  up = false,
  right = false,
  down = false,
  left = false,
  x = window.innerWidth / 2 - 130 / 2,
  y = window.innerHeight / 2 - 130 / 2;

document.addEventListener("keydown", press);

function press(e) {
  if (e.keyCode === 87 /* w */ ) {
    up = true;
  }

  if (e.keyCode === 83 /* S */ ) {
    down = true;
  }

  if (e.keyCode === 65 /* A */ ) {
    if (!left) {
      left = true;

      document.getElementById("girl_flying").src =
        "sprites/characters/girl flying left.gif";
    }
  }

  if (e.keyCode === 68 /* D */ ) {
    if (!right) {
      right = true;

      document.getElementById("girl_flying").src =
        "sprites/characters/girl flying right.gif";
    }
  }
}

document.addEventListener("keyup", release);

function release(e) {
  if (e.keyCode === 87 /* w */ ) {
    up = false;
  }

  if (e.keyCode === 83 /* S */ ) {
    down = false;
  }

  if (e.keyCode === 65 /* A */ ) {
    if (left) {
      left = false;

      document.getElementById("girl_flying").src =
        "sprites/characters/girl flying left.gif";
    }
  }

  if (e.keyCode === 68 /* D */ ) {
    if (right) {
      right = false;

      document.getElementById("girl_flying").src =
        "sprites/characters/girl flying right.gif";
    }
  }
}

function gameLoop() {
  var img = document.getElementById("girl_flying");
  if (up) {
    y = y - 5;
  }
  if (right) {
    x = x + 5;
  }
  if (down) {
    y = y + 5;
  }
  if (left) {
    x = x - 5;
  }
  img.style.left = x + "px";
  img.style.top = y + "px";

  window.requestAnimationFrame(gameLoop);
}
window.requestAnimationFrame(gameLoop);

//end of flying girl controlls
```

```css
/* background / canvas */

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}


/* to remove the top and left whitespace */

html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}


/* just to be sure these are full screen*/

canvas {
  display: block;
}


/* To remove the scrollbars */

body {
  background: rgb(149, 0, 0);
  background: linear-gradient(180deg, rgba(149, 0, 0, 1) 5%, rgba(147, 14, 14, 1) 7%, rgba(154, 22, 31, 1) 13%, rgba(242, 193, 255, 1) 100%);
  );
  background-size: 100vw 100vh;
}


/* background / canvas */


/* girl_flying */

#girl_flying {
  z-index: 0;
  position: fixed;
  left: 100px;
  top: 150px;
}


/* girl_flying */


/* clouds */

#clouds {
  z-index: 1;
  position: fixed;
}


/* clouds */
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>

<head>

  <img id="clouds" src="sprites/background/pink pixel clouds.gif" style="position:fixed; left:10px; top:2px; width=" 450 " 
     height="200 ">
<img id="clouds " src="sprites/background/pink pixel clouds.gif " style = "position:fixed; left:435px; top:5px; width="450" height="200">
  <img id="clouds" src="sprites/background/pink pixel clouds.gif" style="position:fixed; left:925px; top:3px; width=" 425 " 
     height="175 ">
<img id="clouds " src="sprites/background/pink pixel clouds.gif " style = "position:fixed; left:200px; top:100px; width="275" height="150">
  <img id="clouds" src="sprites/background/pink pixel clouds.gif" style="position:fixed; left:800px; top:100px; width=" 275 " 
     height="150 ">
     
<canvas id="canvas "></canvas>

<link type="text/css " rel="stylesheet " href="css/game.css ">
</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript " src="js/girl_flying.js "></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `top = 100;` needs to be `img.style.top = "100px";`

Comment: @ChrisG i copied over what u suggested into the js but i didnt work

Comment: Are you getting error messages in the console? Do you know how to use the developer tools? Press F12 in the browser to see them.

Comment: it says ive got 0 warning and 0 errors. previous to asking this question i did check for anny errors @ChrisG

Comment: There's lots of errors and typos in your HTML alone. Visible stuff like images and canvas do not belong inside <head>, you have no closing quotes after the style attributes (which should be part of your CSS) and there's trailing spaces everywhere, as well as duplicate `id`s. There's little point in debugging your specific problem until you fix the basic syntax.

Comment: well every thing seemed to work fine but i went through and chucked the hmtl, js, css into a formatter and checker and the css being in the html in with the <img> i prefer it because it is not in another file. and i cant find anything that suggests i shoudnt put imgs and canvas in head the tutorial for the character controls put the canvas in the head. but i have done what u suggested. the html is more squished not to my liking but it does look cleaner. with the ids where are these duplicate ids?

Comment: If you are indeed following a tutorial where somebody actually put a canvas inside the <head>, you should definitely look for a different tutorial. The <head> only contains linked scripts and stylesheets, and meta information about the document. All actual content goes into <body>. As for using inline CSS, that's a big no-no in general. You can put a <style> element in <head> and add CSS rules there if you don't want them in a separate file. As for the `id` issue, all your clouds have `id="clouds"` but you're not supposed to give multiple elements the same id.

Comment: Im making a game so if i want all the clouds to disappear i can just get element id then tell all images with that id hide.

Comment: No you can't, because `getElementById('clouds')` will, as the name clearly implies, only select the first one it finds and ignore the rest. I'm not sure why you keep contradicting me about this? There's other methods which do have Element**s** in their name, because they actually return a list of elements, but they don't use the id. You need to use a class instead, period. Assigning the same id to multiple elements on the same page is already invalid, even if you don't use JS at all.

Comment: @chrisg sorry havnt been on in a while. i feel contradicting isnt what im doing. i hadnt got up to the point of testing weather get element id would would and i just did but it seems it doesn't altho the code i had found made me think other wise. and being over text and not face 2 face to listen for tone and facial and body expressions may make me seem like i am contradicting you. when i thought i had found a possible solution so i was just standing by what i thought was the correct answer

Comment: I told you "you're not supposed to give multiple elements the same id" to which you basically replied "I'm doing it because of X" instead of "oh, I didn't know that". And when I told you that actual content like images and canvas don't belong inside <head> you came back with "i cant find anything that suggests i shoudnt put imgs and canvas in head", which is not surprising given how absurd it is in the first place. I mean I've been doing this since 1997, so maybe consider just taking my advice at face value instead of second guessing everything I say? It's really, really basic stuff.

Comment: @ChrisG um yeah i dont take things at face value i like learning hard way so it rlly sticks with me even when a beyond advanced ict person tells me i want to ask questions and go the a different route to see if other ways work.

Comment: That's fine, but there's really no different route here. What you did was produce invalid HTML, and I told you how to fix it. This is not a matter of opinion or best practices. Again, this is very basic stuff. As fundamental as not using drenched wood to make a fire.